# Two columns with big arrow in the figure

Tags: diagrams

Is there any example or template like the follows picture? Thanks!

[image]

(Image source comes from Lu's papger Fig. 2. The multi-party PAKE phase.)

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner. So, I have no idea to solve this problem now. Can you give me some direction. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you want to know about the arrows, so post the code for a minimal document containing the text and maths and somebody will show you how to do the arrows. Right now, this is just a do-this-very-time-consuming-thing-for-me-so-I-don't-have-to. If you post the text/maths, the question will be answerable and focused on something specific i.e. the arrows.

Comment: Does the provided answer solve the problem? If yes, then accept it or leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation using `\leftarrowfill` and `\rightarrowfill`.  By default, the arrows have a length of 2 quads (2em).  You can pass a length argument to have longer (or shorter) arrows; e.g., `\Larrow[10cm]` produces a left arrow of 10cm.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Larrow}[1][2em]{\makebox[#1]{\leftarrowfill}}
\newcommand{\Rarrow}[1][2em]{\makebox[#1]{\rightarrowfill}}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Left arrow: \Larrow
\item Right arrow: \Rarrow
\end{itemize}

A longer left arrow: \Larrow[10cm]

\end{document}
```

**Note.** For entering cryptographic protocols, you can use the `cryptocode` package, available on CTAN at  https://ctan.org/pkg/cryptocode